# Как находить вблизи устройства на Python?

Tags: python, device

Я не знаю, как найти устройство через Python. К примеру - ставишь телефон прямо рядом с ноутбуком. Запускаешь скрипт и он находит это устройство. Показывает его название, IPv4 и т.д. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from scapy.all import *

def arp_monitor_callback(pkt):
    pkt.show()
    print(dict(pkt[DHCP].options[:-1]))

sniff(prn=arp_monitor_callback, filter="udp port 68")
```

Интересные опции

```
{'message-type': 3, 'client_id': b'\x01\xbcj\xd1\xa3\xa5R', 'requested_addr': '192.168.117.38', 'server_id': '192.168.117.1', 'max_dhcp_size': 1500, 'vendor_class_id': b'android-dhcp-12', 'hostname': b'M2101K7BNY', 'param_req_list': [1, 3, 6, 15, 26, 28, 51, 58, 59, 43, 114, 108]}
```

hostname по умолчанию у многих андроидов [совпадает](https://www.google.com/search?q=b%27M2101K7BNY&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) с моделью телефона.

Comment: А вопрос. Почему в filter="upd port 68" там порт 68?

Comment: это dhcp - оно работает на портах 67(сервер),68(клиент)

Comment: Ок. Спасибо большое

Comment: Это самое простое. Потом можешь попробовать пообщаться по mi share, huawei connect, airplay

Comment: А это для какой версии Python? У меня 3.10.0 и DHCP у меня показывает как будто не найдено перменная

Comment: а scapy установил?

Comment: да. Он у меня установлен

Comment: вот так установил pip install scapy

Comment: У меня 3.10. Попробуй импортнуть по полному пути, но у меня из all импортнулось без проблем

Comment: Ок. Попробую...

Comment: У меня эта ошибка:

RuntimeError: Sniffing and sending packets is not available at layer 2: winpcap is not installed. You may use conf.L3socket 
orconf.L3socket6 to access layer 3

Comment: Установи winpcap

Comment: Через pip? Или...

Comment: В PyPi сайте нету библиотеки WinpCap. Есть WinpCapy. Я скачал его. И нечего не работает. Заимпортировал WinpCapy всё равно не работает.

Comment: это не библиотека, а драйвер https://www.winpcap.org/

Comment: Но наверное нужна npcap для вин 10.

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое